# java - float precision when output in console

Tags: java, floating-point

```
float x = 0.98123452f;
System.out.println(x); //it prints out 0.9812345

float x = 0.98123453f;
System.out.println(x); //it prints out 0.98123455
```

I have no idea why the second one's output is 0.98123455 instead of 0.9812345. Isn't the precision of float is 7 decimal digits?

Comment: Not really, nor any other number of decimal digits. It has 23(+1) *bits* of precision. The decimal representation is highly misleading.

Comment: The console has precisely nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IEEE 754 float representation of

```
0.98123453
```

is 32 bits of (sign, exp, mantissa):

```
0 01111110 11110110011001000110000
```

which is:

```
0.9812345504760742
```

in double precision, and cast back to float decimal representation:

```
 0.98123455
```

**The number of bits allocated to a single precision (float) is 32, and 64 bits for double precision. Further note that `BigDecimal` that is frequently suggested will store your number as a string, and not in IEEE754 format.** It will do a conversion when it needs to act on the number, and while it has a better precision, it is awfully slow.

**EDIT.** To clarify why it prints 0.98123455, we need to observe that it is the closest single precision representation of the number 0.98123453:

```
00111111011110110011001000101111 = 0.9812345  (sp) = 0.9812344908714294 (dp)
00111111011110110011001000110000 = 0.98123455 (sp) = 0.9812345504760742 (dp)
00111111011110110011001000110001 = 0.9812346  (sp) = 0.981234610080719  (dp)
```

<sub>sp = single precision, dp = double precision</sub>

The listing is for the [-1,+1] binary range around the number, and you can see that `0.98123453` is closest to the `10000` suffix of the mantissa, while `0.98123452` is closest to the `01111` suffix.

Comment: why it output 8 decimal digits instead of 7?

Comment: Because the double precision of 0.98123452 is 0.9812344908... which is truncated to 0.9812345 for printing. So you should the question the other way around - why is it outputting 7 instead of 8.

Answer (score 2):

The default output format for floating-point in Java is to print just enough digits so that conversion back to the floating-point type produces the original value.

What happens in detail in your code is:

- The source text `0.98123452f` is converted to the `float` value 0.981234490871429443359375.
- This is printed as “0.9812345” because that is just enough digits. The nearest `float` value to 0.9812345 is 0.981234490871429443359375. However, converting “0.981234” to `float` would produce 0.981234014034271240234375, so the “5” is needed.
- The source text `0.98123453f` is converted to the `float` value 0.98123455047607421875.
- This is printed as “0.98123455” because that is just enough digits.

An interesting consequence of this is that, if you assign a `float` value to a `double` object and then print the `double` value, it will often display more digits than printing the `float` value, even though the values are exactly the same. Because the `double` format is finer (more precise) than the `float` format, there may be many `double` values between the value printed for `float` (e.g. 0.9812345) and the actual value (0.981234490871429443359375). Therefore, more digits are needed to distinguish the value.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>To see the exact value of your float, you can use a BigDecimal:</strike>

```
float x = 0.98123452f;
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(x));
```

which outputs: `0.981234490871429443359375`

So technically, this float:

```
float x = 0.981234490871429443359375f;
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(x)); //prints 0.981234490871429443359375
```

has 24 digits precision (it was obviously cherry-picked)...

Forget what is above: BigDecimal only has a double constructor so there was a cast to double and the logic above is flawed.

Bottom line: not all numbers can be represented as a float and the gap between one float and the next one varies depending on the magnitude of the number.

Comment: Well that's because BigDecimal precision isn't IEEE-754 precision. It stores the number as a string.

Comment: @mockinterface Where I made a mistake is that there is no constructor taking a float, so x is actually cast to a double. However "*When a double must be used as a source for a BigDecimal, note that this constructor provides an exact conversion*", according to the javadoc.

Comment: Sure, that just means that it won't convert the double to a string first to forward to the string constructor, preventing you from losing precision even further.

Comment: Actually, every float can be represented by a double exactly. And in turn every double can be represented as a decimal fraction exactly. So the 0.981234490871429443359375 you get is really the mathematically exact value of the float x. This does not mean the accuracy is 24 digits, the value differs from the intended one already in the seventh place.

Answer (score 0):

> isn't the precision of float is 7 decimal digits?

No. It is 23 *binary* digits. The minimum number of decimal digits that can be represented in 23 bits is therefore 6. This is not a mere 'guarantee' as stated in other answers here, it is a mathematical tautology arising from log10(2^23) = 6.92369.

Comment: The significand of an IEEE-754 32-bit binary floating-point object has 24 bits, not 23. 23 are encoded in the significand field, one is encoded via the exponent field.

Answer (score -1):

No, `float` has just six digits of decimal precision.

Comment: I believe it can be more than 6 digits in some cases (but at least 6 in all cases).

Comment: 6–9, indeed. but six is the guaranteed number.